# How to set function's parameter as user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose funciont1(a,b) which has two parameters.(type int)
If I run function1(a,b) *no specific value is inserted.
What I want is: print "Enter a:" and if user types 4, 4 is saved to "a" and "Enter b:" so on.
So I tried

```
def function1(a, b):
    a = int(input('Enter a:'))
    b = int(input('Enter b:'))
```

But when I run function1(a, b) python shows this error: NameError: name 'a' is not defined.
It can be solved by define function1 has no parameters and define variable a, b inside the function1.
But what I want is  set function's parameter as user's input. How to implement like this?

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't parameters here, they're local variables that the function itself sets. You don't want to pass them as parameters. Remove them from the function signature.

Comment: Do parameters only be set by the written code like function1(1,2)?

Comment: If you put `a, b` into `def fun(a, b)`, then the caller of the function must provide values for those parameters. It's for passing values into the function. Obviously you don't want that in this case, since the function itself will be asking the user for the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
def procedure1():
    a = int(input(" Enter a: "))
    b = int(input(" Enter b: "))
```

Comment: First of all have a clear understanding of the difference between a function and procedure.

Comment: Function returns a value to the main program when called. Procedure on the other hand only executes code and does not return a value to main program when called. So your code is a procedure not a function. As already stated by "deceze", a and b are not parameters but local variables to be used by the procedure only unless declared global.

Comment: How? Give me some advice on that.